# Linking Approval Tasks on List Items with SharePoint Designer Workflows

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, tasks, approval-process

I have a simple approval process that I built with SharePoint Designer 2010.  It starts by assigning a task to the user.  The user simply approves and rejects the task.  Based on the status an email is triggered back to the requestor.  Here is my problem, I do not understand how to link that approver task back to the right List Item. I am having trouble understanding the workflow lookup. The condition is not beign recognized of Approve or reject.  Does anyone have an article of how to accomplish an easy lookup as such?  Do I need to set a variable that is reused?

Answer (score 1):

in the 'send email' action, in the content area of the message add a lookup to the current item.

so, in your workflow you will need to set it to fire on creation and on change. so, when the item is created it sends the email to the approver with the link to the item. once the approver changes the 'status' your workflow will fire again sending another email to the creator or whoever with a link to the item.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the "change the behavior of a single task".
Then tap into the "When a task completes" section. Inside this, you have to explicitly set the "Content Approval Status" to Approved\Rejected\Denied (For SPO only)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Source article here](https://threewill.com/sharepoint-workflow-approval-by-only-one-member-of-a-group/?unapproved=97024&moderation-hash=98e704b2ceaebfac7f8ba1751d3b5e63#comment-97024)